# Extract automatically equality between two strings Python on a new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a data frame like this:

```
d = {'col1': ["url/a/b/c/d", "url/b/c/d", "url/j/k", "url/t/y", 'url/r/a/y'],
     'id':   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And I want to create another dataframe based on the original one where I have **only the part of the strings that repeat.**

My idea was to split on each `/` and then compare the first line of the dataframe with the rest of the dataframe (and so one for all lines) to check the equality. Therefore the result for the my initial example on this question will be:

```
result = {'col1': [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["b", "c", "d"], [""], ["y"], ["a", "y"]],
          'id':   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data=result)
```

Moreover I could not build this function without error... any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the part of the strings that repeat*"? Can you break down the logic? Why is the second row of the output `["b"]` but not `["c"]` or `["b", "c", "d"]`?

Comment: Sorry @mozway, and thanks for the call out! Since I could not have a final result using code I did a mistake when I created mine manually to post on the question. Hope now is more clear, I fix the question!

Comment: got it, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract all the wanted parts (several methods are possible), then keep only the duplicated values, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to add the missing empty lists:

```
df['col1'] = (df['col1']
 .str.extractall('/([^/]+)')[0]
 .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)]
 .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
 .reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])
 )
```

Output:

```
           col1  id
0  [a, b, c, d]   1
1     [b, c, d]   2
2            []   3
3           [y]   4
4        [a, y]   5
```